How to refinish this so mold doesnt reappear
Looking for some advice on how to refinish this half wall, mid way down my basement stairs so mold doesn't come back. This was strapped with a couple of horizontal 2x2's with insulation in between and covered with vapour barrier and then drywall.
There is moisture seeping through the foundation (not a crack) that caused mold on the 2x2's and basement landing. I have removed the mold and everything has dried out but I don't want to rebuild it the same as it was before. Any suggestions on how to finish this properly would be greatly appreciated


AFAIK anything you do to finish this won't prevent mold.  Only preventing moisture from coming through the foundation will do that.

The method of construction didn't cause the mold .  The moisture did.  concentrate on curing the issue of moisture infiltration and your cause of mold will be gone.

Would rolling on some sealant to the foundation in this area on the interior help with this? There is a small dip in the pavers here on the exterior of the house as well. I will also have to fix that issue, but it does seem that most of the unfinished areas of the basement have some sort of condensation behind the vapour barrier.

I should add. The condensation only appears in the summer months. Short of digging up the exterior of the house and wrapping the foundation, I'm not totally sure what else could be done about the moisture.

A concrete foundation can be made more water resistant on the outside - interior treatment is not effective. Improve drainage, coat exterior, and apply a membrane over exterior. See https://www.concretenetwork.com/concrete/waterproofing_concrete_foundations/, for example. Yep, it's a fair amount of work to dig down there.
